# jquery-file-upload multiple fields duplicated preview

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I use [blueimp jquery file upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

my problem is when there are two fields like this, and drag one file to one of them, the item will in the preview-section for both.

for example like this:
[image]

how can i prevent that?

============

Ok i **already knew the answer,** pass dropZone in options parameter:

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    dropZone: $('.fileupload')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also did this kind of scenario in my project. you should include separate div tags for each file uploads and give difference ids for each div tags and in your javascript code define dropzone for each id like follow.

```
<div id="example1">
   <!-- include file input -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#example1').each(function () {
    $(this).fileupload({
        dropZone: $(this)
    });
});
```